Screen freeze and session restart often after upgrade to ubuntu 24.04
Error:
déc. 01 01:53:46 thierry-ubuntu kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: unable to load firmware data
déc. 01 01:53:46 thierry-ubuntu kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: init failed, -19
déc. 01 01:53:46 thierry-ubuntu systemd[21202]: Failed to start app-gnome-im\x2dlaunch-21707.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
déc. 01 01:53:46 thierry-ubuntu systemd[21202]: Failed to start app-gnome-snap\x2duserd\x2dautostart-21781.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
déc. 01 01:53:46 thierry-ubuntu systemd[21202]: Failed to start app-gnome-user\x2ddirs\x2dupdate\x2dgtk-21751.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
=====
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 [GeForce GTX 660] [10de:11c0] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. GK106 [GeForce GTX 660] [3842:3061]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

===
cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
GSK_RENDERER=gl

===
Added GSK_renderer as per other posts, reinstalled Nvidia driver. Need to activate X.org as NVIDIA 470 does not recognizes the resolution and the 2 screens but it did not resolve the problem.

Reworded in the main chat as these were different things tried out but it did not help. Too late last night and forgot to mention that it was not resolved.
